# Сервер-клиент на Java

Tags: java, клиент-сервер

Необходимо сделать Сервер-Клиент.

Со стороны сервера - таблица с именами работников и их ID .

Со стороны клиента - программа для добавления нового сотрудника и вытягивания всей таблицы.

Просить реализации было бы сверхнаглостью, поэтому прошу советов и рекомендаций, так как ни разу не сталкивался с этим.

Comment: Если делать по человечески - используя REST / HTTP: вот пример на Spring - http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/ Замените букмарки на сотрудников и вперед.

Comment: @Max Нормально вы так подправили текст вопроса :D

Comment: @StateItPrimitive У человека есть вопрос, а он пишет чуть ли не автобиографию.))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если хотите писать велосипед, то вот самый быстрый на руку вариант клиент-серверного взаимодействия.

Сервер:

```
class TCPServer{
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception{
         String clientSentence;
         String capitalizedSentence;
         ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

         while(true){
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
         }
      }
}
```

Клиент:

```
class TCPClient{
     public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception{
          String sentence;
          String modifiedSentence;
          BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
          DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
          sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
          outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
          modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
          System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
          clientSocket.close();
     }
}
```

Если нужно нормальное решение, то сервлеты, или какую-то библиотеку вроде [netty](https://github.com/netty/netty).

Для работы с базой использовать какую-нибудь ORM вроде [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/).